# Boto failing to authenticate with S3 IAM role

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, amazon-iam

I have a role named Role1. That role has the below policy applied to it.

I have an ec2 instance that has an IAM role of Role1.

When I attempt to conn.get_bucket('fooo_udata') I am returned a 403 error.

Any ideas about this?

```
  {
"Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket","s3:GetBucketLocation","s3:*"],
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::fooo_uadata/","arn:aws:s3:::fooo_uadata/*"]
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject","s3:DeleteObject"],
  "Resource":   ["arn:aws:s3:::fooo_uadata/","arn:aws:s3:::fooo_uadata/*"]
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to include the "/" character on your bucket policies.  So, try changing:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket","s3:GetBucketLocation","s3:*"],
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::fooo_uadata/","arn:aws:s3:::fooo_uadata/*"]
},
```

To this:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket","s3:GetBucketLocation","s3:*"],
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::fooo_uadata","arn:aws:s3:::fooo_uadata*"]
},
```

Since the name of your bucket is `foo_uadata` not `foo_uadata/`.